# Connecting Matlab to a MY SQL Database without database toolbox using javadriver

Tags: mysql, matlab

I need to connect a **MYSQL Database** to Matlab in order to work with the measured data. I am using Matlab version 2014a and unfortunately don't have a Datatoolbox to acces.
I found after a lot of research following instruction:
http://hohonuuli.blogspot.com/2014/10/jdbc-and-matlab-simple-example.html

Unfortunately though it failed to get the connection to the database, I am stucked at the database.m script, while getting following error:

> > database
> >     No method 'getConnection' with matching signature found for class 'java.sql.DriverManager'.

Error in database (line 29)

```
c = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection('url', 'username', 'password',
'mysql-connector-java-5.1.46');
```

I used exactly the script in the following link above ( copy paste ) while putting my username,url,pw etc in.

I am not a programmer by any means but need to find a solution for that, if anyone can help me that would be awesome, THANK IN ADVANCE EIKE

Comment: why you have tagged `javascript` are you using it ?